# Windows 10 ALT+Tab classic always activates file menu [ALT] of second window

Tags: windows-10, alt-tab

First off I'm using the [classic ALT+Tab dialog](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-get-the-old-alt-tab-dialog-in-windows-10/) instead of the gigantic version that is the default in Windows 10.

When I hold `ALT` and tap `Tab` to a window, like Notepad, the file menu is *always* activated! I keep having to escape the file menu for more than half the windows I ALT+Tab to! Is there a fix for this besides going back to Windows 7?

Comment: If you hold ALT then press ALT GR (right ALT) and then press TAB does it opens the classic one or still activates the menu?

Comment: @axys93 I set X-Mouse Button Control and HydraMouse (ClickyMouse doesn't work well or intuitively for me) and set the right-Alt key instead of he left Alt key though unfortunately it didn't help; good idea to check though.

Comment: I have the same issue with Windows 7 and Firefox.

Comment: @C-Otto Use X-Mouse Button Control for Windows 7, set a "Simulated Keys" for your button and then use `{ALT}{TAB}`.

Comment: I don't know what that means. I'm looking for a solution in a corporate environment with a cheap two button mouse plus wheel.

Comment: I'm having the same issue since I upgraded from W7 to W10. In my case, if I Alt-Tab slowly it works fine. But if I do it quickly (as I'm used to), often I get the open menu in my destination window. This is especially bothersome when going to the browser or the calculator. By using AltGr-Tab this doesn't happen as AltGr doesn't open the menu, but of course it's not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using Winaero Tweaker software: 
(no actions on registry is required! **VERY SIMPLE**)

https://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.1836

How to do (easy):

1. Install software
2. Run
3. Select Alt+Tap appearance section
4. Enable checkbox "Enable classic Alt+Tab setting"
5. Click Restart explorer

That's it.

[image]

Comment: Could you please quote the relevant portion so I don't have to go through the entire *very* long page please?

Comment: updated the answer. please check

Comment: I will try this out in a day or two when I have access to a system running 10 natively and have a reminder in my calendar, thank you!

Comment: @John, were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Whatever I tried, (editing the registry, winaero tweaker), I couldn't get the classic alt-tab to work on Win10 2016 LTSB. The solution in the end was to simulate the Right-Alt Tap when pressing Left-Alt using the following AutoIT script. This works for me but may break certain keyboard shortcut combinations that involve both Left Ctrl and Left Alt...

```
#NoTrayIcon
#Region ;**** Directives created by AutoIt3Wrapper_GUI ****
#AutoIt3Wrapper_Run_Au3Stripper=y
#EndRegion ;**** Directives created by AutoIt3Wrapper_GUI ****
#include <WinAPISys.au3>
#include <WinAPI.au3>
#include <Misc.au3>

If _Singleton ( "My_Alt_Tabber", 1 ) = 0 Then
    MsgBox ( 0, "", "Alt tabber is already running!" )
    Exit
EndIf

Dim $LALT = 0xA4
Dim $RALT = 0xA5
Dim $TAB = 0x09
Dim $CTRL = 0x11

Dim $hDLL = DLLOpen ( "user32.dll" )

While True
    If _IsPressed ( "12", $hDLL ) Then
        _KeyDown ($RALT)
        _KeyUp ($RALT)
        _KeyUp ($CTRL)   ; RALT Is actually Ctrl-Alt so must release Ctrl!
        While _IsPressed ( "12", $hDLL )
            ;
        WEnd
    EndIf
WEnd

Func _KeyDown ( $KEY )
    _WinAPI_Keybd_Event ( $KEY, $KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY)
EndFunc

Func _KeyUp ( $KEY )
    _WinAPI_Keybd_Event ( $KEY, $KEYEVENTF_KEYUP)
EndFunc
```