# Alt+Tab vs. Firefox menu

Tags: windows-7, windows, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, alt-tab

My issue is related to the following two questions:

- [Windows 10 ALT+Tab classic always activates file menu [ALT] of second window](https://superuser.com/questions/1026505/windows-10-alttab-classic-always-activates-file-menu-alt-of-second-window)
- [Is the Alt+Tab & Menu Bar interraction broken?](https://superuser.com/questions/1230439/is-the-alttab-menu-bar-interraction-broken)

I am using Firefox 54.0.1 (32-Bit) on Windows 7 Enterprise SP1. My usual work flow is to use Firefox and some other application in turn. To switch back and forth I use the Alt+Tab shortcut.

However, often when I switch to Firefox, the "File" menu is selected (and even opened in case the menu bar is hidden by default). This seems to be related to the exact timing of releasing the keys when switching.

This is extremely annoying, distracting, and wasting my time.

How can I make Windows/Firefox stop doing this?

Comment: strange. I've never seen this after a decade using Firefox

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: of course. and linux. since windows 98